# How to get value from Firebase while using FirebaseUI

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am using Auth Firebase UI. It works like this:
User first time make authentication and after that in onCreate method app creates a new user in Database with the name of user + email + status.
But the problem is that it triggering every onCreate and put all values on default. For example, if I change status in settingsActivity it is changing in the database and everything works well but after I run the app again and my onCreate method in MainActivity triggered my status again become default value. I wanted to check the value with if/else statement and check that value in the database not the same as default but don't know how to get that value. 
Maybe you could advise another scenario? 
Thank you for your time anyway.

```
 //Authstate Listener
    mAuthstateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                Log.v(TAG, "user is not null");
                //Create new user
                String uid = user.getUid();
                String userName = user.getDisplayName();
                mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(uid);
                HashMap<String, String> userMap = new HashMap<>();
                userMap.put("name", userName);
                userMap.put("status", "Your status is here...");
                userMap.put("image", "default");
                userMap.put("thumb_image", "default");
                mDatabaseReference.setValue(userMap);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [read data once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_data_once) using the SingleValueEventListener:

```
            mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(uid);

            mDatabaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if(dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue(String.class).equals("default"))
                    {
                        //the image is still the default one
                    }
                    else{
                        //the image is no longer the default
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
```